# Using old std::string in gcc

Tags: string, c++11, gcc

I have program that uses `std::string`, but `memmove` the std::string` instances.

It worked fine until gcc 5.1.

However this no longer works as of gcc 5.3. I think developers finally did SSO with internal pointer.

I will definitely fix that, but is there easy way to fix it with some define or pragma?

Code looks similar to this:

```
// MyClass have std::string inside
MyClass *a = malloc(MAX * sizeof(MyClass));
// ...
// placement new on a[0]
// ...
memmove(&a[1], &a[0], sizeof(MyClass));
// ...
process(a[1]);
```

This is old code, please do not comment about `malloc` usage.

I will refactor or switch to `std::vector`, but I want the code to work until I do so.

Comment: What you *really* should be doing is not to force the compiler to work with your code, but to refactor your code so it works with modern C++ compilers (and with that I mean everything from the last 15 years or so). That means not using `malloc` to allocate object, or use old C memory copying functions to copy the objects.

Comment: I want code to work until I refactor.

Comment: You can refactor with real placement new on older compiler where this code "works"

Comment: That has been undefined behavior before because your class is neither a POD in C++03 or trivially copyable in C++11. The compiler has every right to do what it wants in this case, and you cannot rely on any behavior, neither in gcc 5.3 or any other version.

Comment: You can tell gcc to use the old abi by setting _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI to 0, but I tthink you then also have to link against the appropriate runtime libs.

Comment: I wonder why it ever worked. If you copy the `std::string` byte-wise, you will have two objects referring to the same internal buffer. Their destructors should delete the same pointer twice. You should definitely run your program with address and undefined behavior sanitizers and check for additional problems.

Comment: @Jens - why not to work? string was a pointer to dinamically allocated memory and size-t for size. But SSO changed this. I believe SSO is inside the size-t and pointer points to this size-t memory.

Comment: @Nick First, it's undefined behavior. That means it may work, format your hard-drive or do anything. Not a good idea. But let's assume you have a string which is a `(pointer, length)` wrapper. The constructor allocate memory and the destructor deallocates it. Now you copy it with `memcopy`. You then have two objects with identical pointer values. Both destructors will deallocate the same pointer. IMHO, the C++ library should ban the old memcpy and add a new one which only works for POD (or TriviallyCopyable) types with `std::enable_if`.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I thought there is easy way to do quick temp fix

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing effects of undefined behavior, but I think you know this. You cannot rely on the effects of byte-wise copying non-POD resp. not trivially copyable types, and the compiler is free to change that behavior.

I think it may be possible to define a safe overload for `memmove` with your class as arguments and use the copy-constructor inside it. I don't know if that is strictly legal, but you seem to be using the C-function instead of the C++ version in namespace `std`, so at least you are not changing namespace `std` which is not allowed.

```
void memmove(MyClass* a, MyClass* b, size_t)
{
    *a = *b;
}
```

Strictly speaking, I think this is still undefined behavior because 17.6.4.3 of the C++ standard specifies that

> If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is
>   reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its
>   behavior is undefined.

In addition, all names in C library are reserved names and shall not be used by the program (17.6.4.3.2). Practically, I think this will work.

You may need to compile with `-fno-builtin` to prevent gcc from replacing `memmove` globally. If it is illegal to overwrite the function, you can replace it dynamically with `LD_PRELOAD`.

This is a hack solution! Your code may still not work because the compiler makes the assumption that, when you `memmove` it is a POD/TriviallyCopyable object and uses that for some optimisation, e.g. by assuming that after the `memmove`, both objects are represented by identical bytes. This is broken when you re-implement `memmove` with the copy-constructor.